# angular ui-router rewrite/redirect url with nginx

Tags: angularjs, redirect, nginx, angular-ui-router, seo

i have an angularjs application with [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) and use nginx.
To create the url for the detail page of a "Track", i use the DB id of this item and the "Track" title. This works great.

If the user change the "Track" title later, the link is broken.
current URL is `https://example.com/23345674298/track-title`
new URL is `https://example.com/23345674298/track-new-title`

How can i redirect the website visitor to the change url?

```
.state('app.track.view', {
  url   : '/{id}/{title}',
  views : {
    'content@': {
      templateUrl : '/app/components/track/trackView.html',
      controller  : 'TrackController',
      controllerAs: 'vm'
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: does `23345674298` is value of `TrackId`?

Comment: @PankajParkar thats correct

Comment: them keep title part as slug don't, take it from URL. Do all operation based on `23345674298 ` (TrackId only), URL can be anything like `https://example.com/23345674298/what-so-ever`

Comment: if i change the ui-router state to `url   : '/{id}/` how i append the slug (title) to the url

Comment: My goal is to make it more SEO friendly.

Comment: just keep your ui-router URL as is. You need to change your implementation in your code a bit. I think you are considering `title` of URL while doing operations, just don't use `title` retrieved from URL, do all operation based on `23345674298 `(TrackId)